# Handling multiple parameters with same name posted to Web API Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have an HTML form which contains a `<select multiple>` element. i.e. The user can select more than one options from the list.  I'm using jQuery to serialise the form data and post it to a Web API Controller (ASP.NET MVC).

The trouble is, the serialisation results in a querystring containing multiple parameters of the same name.  Here's the jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {

    var filters = $('#form').serialize();

    $.getJSON("/Api/GetData?" + filters, function (data) {
        // Do something with data
    });

});
```

The resultant API call is like:

```
/Api/GetData?selection=1234&selection=7432&selection=23
```

The API Controller seems to only accept the first value for the 'selection' parameter.  It's doing something like this:

```
public void GetData(string selection){
    …
}
```

I wondered, is there a way to get the API controller to treat the parameters as a collection, or should that be handled client-side i.e. by ensuring that the parameter values are sent as a comma-separated list (`/Api/GetData?selection=1234,7432,23`).  If the latter, is there a neat way to do this rather than building the querystring manually?

Many thanks.

Comment: `string selection` -> `string[] selection`

Comment: you can use array and push all the required values inside the array, then use POST call in jquery.

Comment: This is how your url should look like: [Including Arrays in URI Requests](https://wp-mix.com/arrays-uri-requests/)

Comment: @Reniuz that's for PHP. It does not work like that for MVC/WebAPI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah...I was thinking about bad url and tried to point to the format...nonsense...it's Friday you know :)

Comment: @Reniuz no problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I found changing the controller parameter works:

```
public void GetData([FromUri] string[] selection){
```

(It seems to require the [FromUri] decorator)

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that you were making a GET request. Glad you got it working.